# Jetty binary message websocket throughput

Tags: websocket, jetty

I'm only getting about 6 mb/s throughput for binary messages on one connection over the loopback. The actual messages are about 100k to 1mb in size. Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Post your code and configuration for your test.  Cometd benchmarks for Jetty websocket can saturate the network, so its likely not a flaw in Jetty.

Comment: Nevermind, the producer was actually rate-limited to 30fps.